# Can I use a non-EV certificate to sign a driver after Windows 10 RTM release?

Tags: c, windows, driver

I am developing a **kernel-mode driver** and I 'd like it to be able to run on all Windows platforms (including Windows 10). I have read the driver signing policy in Win10 from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_hardware_certification/archive/2015/04/01/driver-signing-changes-in-windows-10.aspx. I don't know if I am understanding it right, does it mean that **if I buy a non-EV cert before Win10 release (AKA 2015/7/29), I can still use the cert to sign a driver to any platform including Win10 until the cert expires**. For example, I can just buy a 3-year long cert before 7/29 and use it to sign any drivers for these 3 years (the longest period for a cert seems to be 3 years). 3 years later, I have no other choice but to buy an EV cert, is this understanding right? Thanks.

Comment: After one year, does the answer to this question have any updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically asking if you can slip a driver that wasn't signed with Extended Validation ("EV") certificate through the door before Windows 10 release.

The salient point is this:

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_hardware_certification/archive/2015/04/01/driver-signing-changes-in-windows-10.aspx
>
> Beginning with the release of Windows 10, all new Windows 10 kernel
>   mode drivers must be submitted to and digitally signed by the Windows
>   Hardware Developer Center Dashboard portal.  Windows 10 will not load
>   new kernel mode drivers which are not signed by the portal.

My guess is "maybe".

But you'd better hurry.

And you'd better have a Plan B if your Windows 10 customers discover that your driver won't work.

Comment: Hi, I don't know if you understand me right, what I want is not just slip a driver, but slip a certificate, I want to buy a non-EV certificate from Symantec and use this certificate to sign drivers in the following 3 years. I have known that the drivers signed before Win10 RTM release will work on Win10, so this is not what I asked.

Comment: One more link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.  "Windows 10 for desktop editions (Home, Pro, and Enterprise) and Windows Server Technical Preview kernel-mode drivers must be signed by the Windows Hardware Dev Center Dashboard and the Windows Hardware Dev Center Dashboard requires an EV certificate. For more info about these changes, see [Driver Signing Changes in Windows 10](http://bit.ly/1CParx5)".  Again - if you want to try it: better hurry, and better have a Plan B.

Comment: I saw that link, I know MS wants us to use EV certificate, but this is not what I asked. Why I don't try it is even a 3-year non-EV cert is not cheap, I don't want to buy one to see that it can't be used to sign drivers for Win10 after Win10 RTM release.

Comment: Two more links: [Extended Validation Code Signing Certificiate](https://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=265015), and [Microsoft Signatures to be REQUIRED for Windows 10 Kernel-Mode Drivers](https://www.osr.com/blog/2015/03/18/microsoft-signatures-required-km-drivers-windows-10/).  'Hope that helps ... and you have my sympathy...

Comment: OK, I saw "These requirements only apply to Windows 10 and later.  In fact, Microsoft plans to offer a bit of a grace period: Drivers signed before Windows 10 RTM will be able to use the older signing mechanisms.  But once Windows 10 ships, if you want your driver to run on Windows 10 desktop systems, you’ll need to (a) get an EV certificate, (b) using that signature submit your driver to sysdev to get Microsoft’s signature." in your link, so I think the answer is NO, thanks!

Comment: To repeat: if you want to support Windows 10 .. and you don't want to purchase an EV certificate ... then a) you'd better hurry, and b) you'd better have a fallback if things don't work out for your Windows 10 customers.  Good luck!

Comment: My project is going on these months, and it's hard for me to release a final   version before Win10 RTM release. Currently I have a one-year non-EV cert, I think I will try this cert on Win10 after its release, if it didn't work I will buy an EV cert then.

Comment: @paulsm4 Hi, after one year, does the answer to this question have any updates?